# How to use switch user windows instead of screensaver on Gnome?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gui

I want to use switch user window instead of screensaver, but can't find the way to do it.

Lock screen hotkey - calls the screensaver window:

[image]

But is it possible to use Ubuntu switch user window instead of it?

[image]

Can't even find a terminal command to call that window
Can you help with it?

---

Ubuntu 16.04
Gnome shell 3.18.5

Screenshots taken from the web.